# Android. StaggeredGridLayoutManager places the cells in the wrong position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

I use a recyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager. I have two columns, cells in columns can be of different heights. The items are positioned fine, however on some devices I noticed the following problem. Suppose I have a list of elements: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H. Visually, it looks like this:

[image: My columns image]

I expected that the G element would be in the left column, since the elements are located from left to right, tell me what might be the reason for this behavior. I need the element to be in the left column. The G element should fit into the free position of the left column, but it is located on the right, which is incorrect for me
This is only playable on some devices.
I expect this order of element, in the left column: A,C,E,G, in the right column: B,D,F,H.
I try to set gapStrategy to GAP_HANDLING_NONE, but after that my items are not showing:

```
sglm.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE
```

Comment: See the changes

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your LayoutManager to fill up the gaps, you can change the gapStrategy like this

```
    val lm = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(...)

    lm.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE
```

default handling is

```
lm.gapStrategy = StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_MOVE_ITEMS_BETWEEN_SPANS
```

Comment: When I set gapStrategy  StaggeredGridLayoutManager.GAP_HANDLING_NONE, my elements no showing. Why is this happening?